# Linear Algebra, add these two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be a natural number $\geq 2$ and $A$ a matrix $\in M_{n}(K)$. We suppose the matrices $A$ and $I_{n}+A$ are invertible.

Calculate: $(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}$

I know the result is $I_{n}$ but i don't understand why. Here's my effort:

$(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{-1}+(A)^{-1}=(A)+A^{-1}$

I'm assuming $I_{n}+A=A$ ?

Where did i go wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you get $(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^{-1}+(A)^{-1}$?

Comment: Well i just thought that adding an indentity matrix to a A matrix = A

Comment: That's not true at all!  What is true is that when you _multiply_ a matrix by the identity matrix it doesn't change.

Comment: how should i proceed then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is the accepted answer, I feel obliged to give a short, quick and effective proof which holds in full generality. This is:

$$(I+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}=A\cdot A^{-1}(I+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}$$
$$=A\cdot \bigg((I+A^{-1})A\bigg)^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}=A\cdot (A+I)^{-1}+(A+I)^{-1} $$
$$=(A+I)(A+I)^{-1}=I.$$

But I also think there is some value to the original proof I gave (although it only holds for real and complex matrices). Therefore, I leave it below.

---

First, consider the sets $\mathcal{A}:=\{A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C}) \mid \exists A^{-1}\}$. and $\mathcal{B}:=\{B \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C}) \mid \exists (I+B)^{-1}\}$. Those are open sets. Put $\mathcal{N}:=\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B}$ and consider the function

$$f: \mathcal{N} \rightarrow M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$$
$$A \mapsto (I+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}.$$

It follows from the chain rule and the well-known formula for the derivative of the inverse mapping that

$$D_Xf(\cdot) =-(I+X^{-1})^{-1}(-X^{-1}\cdot X^{-1})(I+X^{-1})^{-1}-(I+X)^{-1}\cdot (I+X)^{-1}.$$

$$=(X+I)^{-1}\cdot(X+I)^{-1}-(I+X)^{-1}\cdot (I+X)^{-1}=0.$$

$\mathcal{N}$ is connected. A proof of this is outlined below.

> It suffices to prove that each matrix has a path to $I$. Therefore, take a matrix $A \in \mathcal{N}$. Due to density of matrices with different eigenvalues and openness of $\mathcal{N}$, there exists a matrix $K=PDP^{-1}$ near $A$ that can be joined to $A$ by a segment. Now, join $PDP^{-1}$ to $I$ by sending the diagonal entries to $1$ through a path which does not go through $0$ or $-1$ (using path-connectedness of $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0,-1\})$.

It then suffices to compute $f$ in any given point. We compute $f(I)$:

$$f(I)= (2I)^{-1}+(2I)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{1}{2}I=I.$$

Hence, $f$ is constant and equal to $I$. $\blacksquare$

(Note that since we've proved the proposition for matrices with complex entries, this holds also for real entries as well. It is also worth noting that I don't see how it would be possible to generalize this technique to an arbitrary field, since we heavily use differentiable properties and the topology of $\mathbb{C}$.)

*Thanks to Aaron for helpful comments regarding this answer!

Comment: phew okay, i think I have some studying to do because there is no way i would have come out with that on my own.

Comment: @spexel: While this is a neat answer, I doubt it is the argument you were expected to come up with!  Something similar to my answer is probably the intended solution.

Comment: @EricWofsey And it is not so neat after all. There are some issues with my answer, which I'm trying to address right now (the function is not defined in the whole domain, for instance). But I think I'll manage to solve them.

Comment: The first part of the argument is a bit of a red herring: you have explicitly computed the value of the function on the diagonalizable matrices, and by continuity, you have found it everywhere.

Comment: @Aaron You are absolutely right. I made appropriate changes.

As a sidenote, I should say that this answer, which had intention of being concise, became quite convoluted. Although I think this answer may still present some value, I think it is appropriate to consider, in regards to this question, the other answers given much more suitable.

Answer (score 5):

Since $(I+A^{-1})=A^{-1}(I+A)$, we have

$$(I+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}=(A^{-1}(I+A))^{-1}+(I+A)^{-1}=(I+A)^{-1}\left(\left(A^{-1}\right)^{-1}+I\right)=(I+A)^{-1}(I+A)=I,$$

where at the last stage we used that $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$.

Comment: It's worth commenting that because everything here is in terms of $A$ and $I$ (and the inverse operator), everything in sight commutes, so I was a little bit sloppy with which side I was factoring/multiplying things on.  Any apparent "errors" here having to do with commutativity are very easily repaired.  Any undergrad should view the answer with slight suspicion.  Nobody in grad school should.

Answer (score 3):

Write $B=(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}$.  Can you compute the product $(I_n+A^{-1})B(I_n+A)$?  If you can show that $$(I_n+A^{-1})B(I_n+A)=(I_n+A^{-1})(I_n+A),$$ then multiplying both sides by $(I_n+A^{-1})^{-1}$ on the left and $(I_n+A)^{-1}$ on the right, you get $B=I_n$.

Comment: I don't know how to find the product of $(I_{n}+A^{-1})B(I_{n}+A)$ and even if i did i don't understand the reason for doing that :(

Comment: Well, let's pretend we just had numbers instead of matrices.  Then we're trying to show that $(1+a^{-1})^{-1})+(1+a)^{-1}=1$, or $\frac{1}{1+a^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+a}=1$.  To show this, you might multiply by $1+a^{-1}$ and $1+a$ to clear the denominators of the fractions.  The idea here is the same; you just have to be a bit more careful because when you multiply matrices it can matter what order you multiply them in.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is an easier way to do that, just using basic matrix calculus - the argument by Aloizio Macedo however seems to be really elegant though. Let's suppose we already guessed that the following solution holds
$$
(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}=I_n
$$
for all suitable $A$. It is reasonable to assume this because, as usual, we just make some educated guessing with $A=I_n$, and $A$ some diagonal matrices in general.

Next step is we just verify this by doing the following steps
\begin{align}
& & (I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}&=I_n \\
&\iff & (I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}(I_{n}+A)+I_n&=(I_{n}+A) \\
&\iff & (I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}(I_{n}+A)&=A \\
&\iff & I_n(I_{n}+A)&=(I_{n}+A^{-1})A \\
&\iff & (I_{n}+A)&=(A+I_n)\\
&\iff & A&=A
\end{align}
which is a true statement. Therefore 
$$
(I_{n}+A^{-1})^{-1}+(I_{n}+A)^{-1}=I_n
$$
holds indeed for all suitable $A$.