# Is there a citation for this interesting relationship?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, reference-request

While preparing a manuscript for publication, I recently found the following relationship:

1/(1+ratio) + 1/(1+(1/ratio)) = 1

which appears to hold true for any ratio or value except 0 and -1

I expect that this relationship has been discussed somewhere else before, but it may have been a long time ago. It could have been as far back as the Enlightenment Period, when Euler, Wallis, and many others laid the foundations for many areas of math.

Any help in tracking down a citation for this interesting relationship would be appreciated.

Comment: The second term on the LHS is $r/(1+r)$.

Comment: Also, $x+(1-x)=1$. Neat.

Comment: What kind of manuscript? What is "ratio", and how did your expression pop up?

Comment: Yes, so if the second term is equal to r/(1+r), then 1/(1+r)+r/(1+r)=1 is pretty trivial. Probably this relationship doesn't need a citation at all.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: This came up while using Critical Ratios (CR) to describe structural characteristics of triacylglycerols using mass spectrometry. The solution for the sum of all ions, [MH] + [AB] + [AA], was 1+1/(CR1x(1+CR2))+1/(CR1x(1+1/CR2), which rearranges to 1+1/CR1x(1/(1+CR2)+1/(1+1/CR2)). Now, (1/(1+ratio)+1/(1+1/ratio))=1, so the last term in the sum cancels out, and the sum becomes simply 1+1/CR1.  The ratio can be any value except 0 or -1, but for my application, Critical Ratio 1 was [MH]/Sum[DAG] and Critical Ratio 2 was [AA]/[AB], from mass spectrometry of ABA/AAB/BAA triacylglycerols

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra, add these two matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484849/linear-algebra-add-these-two-matrices)

Comment: @Aloizio: Although I was not using matrices, the solution seems to be entirely analogous. Is there a citation for (I+A^-1)^-1 + (I+A)^-1 = I ? The comment on that post by Eric contains the relationship I mentioned. Maybe it is so fundamental it doesn't require a literature citation.